# Own Goal adds to Career Stats?

Tags: rules, football, trivia, statistics, own-goal

I love watching football. I have an interesting doubt. Did the **Own Goal(OG)** scored by the player(obviously by mistake) adds to his career stats? OR Its ignored?

Comment: Unsure what you're asking. Are you asking whether own goals are tracked? Are you asking if own goals are counted towards a player's goals scored stat?

Comment: I am talking about player's career stat.

Comment: When two people voted to accept an edit over your single vote to reject, changing that edit unilaterally is ignoring the point of review. Please do not circumvent processes which are designed to prevent exactly that type of event.

Answer (score 0):

Own goals do not contribute to offensive goal statistics and are simply counted as a different statistic altogether, as you said "OG". This statistic would be tracked throughout a players career however, and a full description of the exact rules regarding own goals can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Own_goal).

Answer (score -1):

No, first of all, exactly because considering the one player and team's perpective, is not considered a *goal scored*, but a goal against.

You see, the underline tone of football is movement: it's the movement that decides almost all if not all rules of the game.

Because of this, the movement resulting into one own goal is **never** considered a direct action by one player, but an involuntary one. That's why the own goal is a special kind of goal: for instance, that is the main reason why one player cannot score an own goal directly from a free kick (a corner is given to the opposing team), but he *can* score if he kicks into the the opponents’ goal.

Regarding statistics, usually at the end of each season, all the o.g. are sometimes anonymously summed up together to the list of all goals scored by one particular team, sometimes the names are present, out of curiosity.

Comment: Hi JVP... generally better answers at StackExchange are those with references backing them up. Or at least explanation of experience giving expertise on the subject (such as being a sports statistician or perhaps time scoring games). A little more footing about where/how regularly you've seen the odd count you mention in your final paragraph would help. Indeed this question seems rather straightforward, so to most the answer is as you state it... but if someone is asking, the opinion must not be unanimous, and so it's best to have something concrete to stand upon for such answers. Cheers! :-)